# Почему возникает ошибка OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java

Вводится из консоли дата (тип String). При посимвольном сравнении, на второй вводимой дате вылетает ошибка `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class Goods implements Serializable {       //класс "Товары". каждый товар - объект.

    private String name;
    private String currency;
    private String date;
    private int cost;

    Goods(String name, String cost, String currency, String date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = Integer.parseInt(cost);
        this.currency = currency;
        this.date = date;
    }

    String getName(){return name;}
    int getCost(){ return cost;}
    String getCurrency(){return currency;}
    String getDate(){return date;}
}



class ShowGoods {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);

        String str;
        String parts[] = new String[5];
        ArrayList <Goods> myGoods = new ArrayList<>();      // массив объектов-товаров
        Goods nextGood, comGood;        // пременные для работы с объектами-товарами из массива

        pw.println();
        pw.println("Enter the purchase. Format: purchase 2019-04-25 12 USD 'Photo Frame' ");
        pw.println("The input end sign is string 'stop'.");
        do {
            str = br.readLine();

            if(str.compareTo("stop") == 0) break;

            int i=0;

            for (String retval : str.split(" ", 5)) {
                parts[i] = retval;
//              System.out.println(parts[i]);
                i++;
            }

            switch(parts[0]) {

                case "purchase":

                    Goods good1 = new Goods(parts[4], parts[2], parts[3], parts[1]);

                    if( myGoods.size() > 0) {

                        String goodDate, nextDate;

                        done:
                        for(int j=0; j < myGoods.size(); j++) {         // сравнение даты вводимой покупки с уже введёнными
                            nextGood = myGoods.get(j);
                            goodDate = good1.getDate();
                            nextDate = nextGood.getDate();

                            for(int k=0; k<10; k++) {           // посимвольное сравнение дат. Вот здесь вылетает OutOfMemoryError: 
                                char g1 = goodDate.charAt(k);
                                char ng = nextDate.charAt(k);
                                if(g1 < ng) {
                                    myGoods.add(j, good1);
                                    break done;
                                }
                            }
                            if( j==(myGoods.size() - 1) ) myGoods.add(good1);   // !!! только что еще раз прогнал, указало эту строку !!!
                        }
                    } else myGoods.add(good1);
                break;


        } while(str.compareTo("stop") != 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо бы коде отметить место, где у Вас вылетает Exception

Comment: В цикле   for(int k=0; k<10; k++) {   // посимвольное сравнение дат. Если его удаляю, то всё нормально. Только даты не сравниваются :(

Comment: Прямо в коде внутри этого цикла отметьте комментарием строку где программа валиться. Это сэкономит время людей которые вынуждены анализировать Ваш код, не имея возможности прогнать его пошагово через отладчик.  Еще вопрос, а нет ли в Java более простого способа сравнивать даты?

Comment: В коде указал строку, которая выпадает в консоли.

Comment: А ещё лучше добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: если не секрет а кто Вас научил пользоваться break с меткой?

Comment: У вас в коде неверно расставлены скобки {}. Не удалось воспроизвести проблему. Все отрабатывает без OOME

Comment: По поводу break с меткой, ни кто не учил. Сам пытаюсь осилить, читаю Шилда. Ну и Google в помощь.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   -at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)   -at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)   -at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(Unknown Source)   -at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)   -at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)   -at TestProblem.ShowGoods.main(ShowGoods.java:81)

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Проблема была в том, что не прерывался внешний FOR. Это и приводило к переполнению. А заодно и переписал кусок для сравнения дат (отдельное спасибо Александр Муксимов)))